# How to show double 00 like 00:00:59 in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a time like this:
00:00:59;
But I can't get it to show 00 instead it show only one 0.

Comment: You're going to have to show us your code.

Comment: Why the heck my post always get minus score?
English is not my first language and if you fail understand that then I can say that your life will be fail too. SMH

Comment: It's because it's *severely* lacking in quality. No code. No evidence of an attempt. Not even an actual question.

Comment: My question was to find a keyword call setw(). Why do I need to write a code when there is nothing to write down? Or maybe I should write "Hello, world" code? -- more wtf this stack exchange thing....

Comment: How were we to know you were after `std::setw`? For all we knew you could be using `std::strftime`, or some third-party library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way using `std::setw` and `std::setfill` is this:

```
int hour = 0;
int minute = 0;
int second = 59;

std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << hour << ":";
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << minute << ":";
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << second << endl;
```

It will print:

```
00:00:59
```